# PHP file include - permission denied on Windows 7

Tags: php, apache

Just installed Apache 2.2 (installed as a module) and latest PHP build on my local win 7 machine. However when I try to include a file I ma getting a permission denied error. 
I tried all kinds of combination of permission setting but nothing works. Does anyone know if there is a good write up on this problem? or if you could include instructions that would be great.

BTW - the file is there and the code is fine. This is definitely a permissions problem.

Comment: Why didn't you post a complete error as-is?

Comment: Please show the code and the error

Comment: What dir is apache in, what dir is php in? Where is the site, where is the file you are trying to include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this. It was not a permissions problem. The library which I was trying to include for a bizarre reason got encrypted by stooopid windows. Thanks for listening.